# React element events

Tags: reactjs

So I'm trying to style an element when user focuses/hovers on an input/button. The way I'm doing it is by using a state and setting it to true or false if the user has hovered or focused but find it very repetitive and will take a lot of code, considering I would have to create a focused and hovered state for each button or input.
For example, I'm doing :

```
 const [hoveredBtn, setHoveredBtn] = useState(false)
 const [themecolor, setThemecolor]=useState('red') //this state is being from firebase, red would 
  //just be an example, it can be whatever the user sets it to.
 return (
 <button 
 onMouseOver={()=>setHoveredBtn(true)} 
onMouseLeave={()=>setHoveredBtn(false)} 
style={hoveredBtn?{backgroundColor: themecolor}:{backgroundColor:"white"}}
 >
Button
 </button>
 )
```

Therefore, I would need to create a hovered variable for each button or input I have and im looking to know if there is a way to do it like this, but when I tried I get an error:

```
 return (
  <button onMouseOver={this.style.color=themecolor} onMouseLeave= 
 {this.style.color='white'}>Button</button>
  )
```

Comment: why use javascript for this - css would be better.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t specify pseudo-classes using inline styles. That means `:hover`, `:focus`, `:active`, or `:visited` go out the window rather than the component.
source: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/react-styled-components-inline-styles-3-other-css-styling-approaches-with-examples/

`style.css`:

```css
.myComponent:hover {
    // define style
}
```

`myReactComponent.jsx`:

```js
import './style.css';
```

Comment: I can’t use css because I’m making an app where the user has access to changing the theme color of the app, so unless I can put a dynamic color, it wouldn’t work

Comment: In that case, I would use the `styled-components` library: https://styled-components.com/

Comment: thanks for the recommendation, exactly what I'm looking for